# Parsing json from weather api

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I am attempting to parse a response back from the api at https://www.worldweatheronline.com.

I am getting these results (I cut it short due to the character limitation on posts):

```
{{
  "data": {
    "request": [
      {
        "type": "LatLon",
        "query": "Lat 33.41 and Lon -86.94"
      }
    ],
    "nearest_area": [
      {
        "areaName": [
          {
            "value": "Brickyard Junction"
          }
        ],
        "country": [
          {
            "value": "United States of America"
          }
        ],
        "region": [
          {
            "value": "Alabama"
          }
        ],
        "latitude": "33.410",
        "longitude": "-86.942",
        "population": "0",
        "weatherUrl": [
          {
            "value": "http://api-cdn.worldweatheronline.com/v2/weather.aspx?q=33.408696,-86.937835"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "weather": [
      {
        "date": "2019-03-20",
        "astronomy": [
          {
            "sunrise": "06:52 AM",
            "sunset": "06:59 PM",
            "moonrise": "06:47 PM",
            "moonset": "06:51 AM",
            "moon_phase": "Waxing Gibbous",
            "moon_illumination": "97"
          }
        ],
        "maxtempC": "20",
        "maxtempF": "69",
        "mintempC": "8",
        "mintempF": "46",
        "totalSnow_cm": "0.0",
        "sunHour": "11.6",
        "uvIndex": "5",
        "hourly": [
          {
            "time": "0",
            "tempC": "9",
            "tempF": "49",
            "windspeedMiles": "4",
            "windspeedKmph": "7",
            "winddirDegree": "65",
            "winddir16Point": "ENE",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png"
              }
            ],
            "weatherDesc": [
              {
                "value": "Clear"
              }
            ],
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "humidity": "53",
            "visibility": "10",
            "pressure": "1026",
            "cloudcover": "2",
            "HeatIndexC": "9",
            "HeatIndexF": "49",
            "DewPointC": "0",
            "DewPointF": "33",
            "WindChillC": "9",
            "WindChillF": "47",
            "WindGustMiles": "7",
            "WindGustKmph": "11",
            "FeelsLikeC": "9",
            "FeelsLikeF": "47",
            "uvIndex": "0"
          },
          {
            "time": "100",
            "tempC": "9",
            "tempF": "49",
            "windspeedMiles": "4",
            "windspeedKmph": "6",
            "winddirDegree": "70",
            "winddir16Point": "ENE",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png"
              }
            ],
            "weatherDesc": [
              {
                "value": "Clear"
              }
            ],
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "humidity": "54",
            "visibility": "10",
            "pressure": "1026",
            "cloudcover": "2",
            "HeatIndexC": "9",
            "HeatIndexF": "49",
            "DewPointC": "0",
            "DewPointF": "33",
            "WindChillC": "9",
            "WindChillF": "47",
            "WindGustMiles": "6",
            "WindGustKmph": "10",
            "FeelsLikeC": "9",
            "FeelsLikeF": "47",
            "uvIndex": "0"
          },
          {
            "time": "200",
            "tempC": "9",
            "tempF": "48",
            "windspeedMiles": "4",
            "windspeedKmph": "6",
            "winddirDegree": "76",
            "winddir16Point": "ENE",
            "weatherCode": "116",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png"
              }
            ],
            "weatherDesc": [
              {
                "value": "Partly cloudy"
              }
            ],
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "humidity": "55",
            "visibility": "10",
            "pressure": "1026",
            "cloudcover": "1",
            "HeatIndexC": "9",
            "HeatIndexF": "48",
            "DewPointC": "0",
            "DewPointF": "33",
            "WindChillC": "8",
            "WindChillF": "47",
            "WindGustMiles": "5",
            "WindGustKmph": "9",
            "FeelsLikeC": "8",
            "FeelsLikeF": "47",
            "uvIndex": "0"
          },
          {
            "time": "300",
            "tempC": "9",
            "tempF": "48",
            "windspeedMiles": "3",
            "windspeedKmph": "5",
            "winddirDegree": "82",
            "winddir16Point": "E",
            "weatherCode": "116",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png"
              }
            ],
            "weatherDesc": [
              {
                "value": "Partly cloudy"
              }
            ],
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "humidity": "56",
            "visibility": "10",
            "pressure": "1025",
            "cloudcover": "1",
            "HeatIndexC": "9",
            "HeatIndexF": "48",
            "DewPointC": "0",
            "DewPointF": "33",
            "WindChillC": "8",
            "WindChillF": "47",
            "WindGustMiles": "5",
            "WindGustKmph": "8",
            "FeelsLikeC": "8",
            "FeelsLikeF": "47",
            "uvIndex": "0"
          },
```

I am attempting to parse the json results back and getting a null value.

```
private async Task<List<HourData>> GetDataAsync()
{
  try
  {
    var datas = new List<HourData>();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_url);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

      JObject obj = JObject.Parse(content);

      var token = obj.SelectToken("weather"); // *** NullReferenceException HERE
      var tokenHours = (JArray) token.SelectToken("hourly");

      foreach (var tk in tokenHours)
      {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tk);
        datas.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HourData>(json));
      }
    }
    // return product;

    return datas;

  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
  }
}

  public class HourData
  {
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string PrecipIntensity { get; set; }
    public string PrecipProbability { get; set; }
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
    public string ApparentTemperature { get; set; }
    public string DewPoint { get; set; }
    public string Humidity { get; set; }
    public string Pressure { get; set; }
    public string windSpeed { get; set; }
    public string windGust { get; set; }
    public string windBearing { get; set; }
    public string cloudCover { get; set; }
    public string uvIndex { get; set; }
    public string visibility { get; set; }
  }
```

I am getting a `NullReferenceException` at this line `var token = obj.SelectToken("weather");`.

I have also tried the following and got the same results:

```
      var token = obj.SelectToken("data");
      var tokenHours = (JArray) token.SelectToken("weather");
```

I need to get the hourly data in to my class array but it's not parsing.

Am I parsing on the wrong word? I'm lost as to why it's not parsing correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By "null exception", do you mean a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @Amy exactly that.

Comment: There are other kinds of "null exceptions".  It's important to be specific.

Comment: If you're getting a `NullReferenceException` on that line in particular, it may be that `obj` is not properly getting populated. Have you stepped in with the debugger to ensure that `JObject.Parse(content);` is succeeding?

Comment: @FlutterDashie Thanks for the reply. I am getting a result back from the parse, the json that is posted above is the results.

Comment: Have you looked at the sample projects on their website? https://www.worldweatheronline.com/developer/api/code-examples.aspx

Comment: @ErocM so `obj` is populating, then? If so, you should be able to do `obj.Children()` to get a collection of every `JToken` inside your data, and potentially print or view it for debugging purposes by doing a `foreach` or LINQ statement to see what is going on in the C# side of things.

Comment: @EdneyHolder Actually I hadn't. I'm blind and overlooked that part of the site. I'll check it out now.

Comment: `{{` is not proper JSON and makes me think that is not what you actually get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't went to the correct elements.

changing this 2 lines from:

```
var token = obj.SelectToken("weather"); // *** NullReferenceException HERE
var tokenHours = (JArray) token.SelectToken("hourly");
```

to:

```
var token = obj.SelectToken("data.weather"); // *** NO NULL EXCEPTION HERE
var tokenHours = (JArray)token[0].SelectToken("hourly");
```

fixed your code.

first the weather is inside the data element.
second the weather is an array so you need to address the correct index (or you can change it to loop).

Comment: Perfect! Tyvm for the explanation!